# Execute C/C++/Objective-C code file via BASH script (on Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, bash, gcc, g++, clang

So, I need a script which **takes a filepath as an input** and **compiles & executes the code (either C,C++, or Objective-C).**

I admit I'm not a BASH guru... So, ***is there a better way to do it?*** What would you change (and why)?

Here's my code...

---

**C**

```
input=$1;
output=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
newinput="$output.c"
cp $input $newinput

gcc $newinput -o $output -std=c99

status=$?

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then
$output
exit 0
elif [ $status -eq 127 ]
then
echo "gcc :: Compiler Not found"
fi

exit $status
```

---

**C++**

```
input=$1;
output=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
newinput="$output.cpp"
cp $input $newinput

g++ $newinput -o $output

status=$?

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then
$output
exit 0
elif [ $status -eq 127 ]
then
echo "g++ :: Compiler Not found"
fi

exit $status
```

---

**Objective-C**

```
input=$1;
output=`echo "$1" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
newinput="$output.m"
cp $input $newinput

clang $newinput -o $output -ObjC -std=c99 -framework Foundation

status=$?

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then
$output
exit 0
elif [ $status -eq 127 ]
then
echo "gcc :: Compiler Not found"
fi

exit $status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not specify if you want your script to compile the source to a unique file, or if you want that executable binary file to be removed. Maybe you could for *C* use  something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
input=$1
## unique files for C code and for binary executable
cfile=$(tempfile -s .c)
binfile=$(tempfile -s .bin)
## ensure they are removed at exit or interrupts
trap "/bin/rm -f $cfile $binfile" EXIT QUIT INT TERM
cp $input $cfile
if gcc $cfile -o $binfile; then
  $binfile
else
  echo C compilation of $input thru $cfile failed
  exit 1
fi
```

and if you are sure you are using specifically `gcc` to compile, you might use its [-x option](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options) as `gcc -x c $input -o $binfile` without bothering copying the input to a `.c` suffixed file named `$cfile`. You could be tempted to also pass `-Wall -Werror -g -O` to `gcc`. And you should trust the file you are getting this way (there is a security risk, e.g. if that file contains `system ("/bin/rm -rf $HOME");` etc).

I have no idea if your MacOSX system have `gcc` (perhaps it is `clang` or `cc`) and the `tempfile` utility to make temporary file names (perhaps it is `mktemp` which should be invoked differently).